# How can I define typedef matrix in ansi c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, typedef

I have 2 .c files, adj.c and main.c.
 What i try to do is to define at adj.c

```
#define N 12
typedef int adj_mat[N]
```

and use this typedef at main.c as two dimensional array
I tried to define like this,

```
adj_mat mat[N];
```

I have a fucntion in my program that fills this matrix with zero, with definition:

```
void fill_mat_zero(adj_mat);
```

My problem that if i run this program with Visual studio there are no problems,
but if i try to compile it in Ubuntu it shows me an error that looks like:
note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[12]’

What is the problem here? The definiton of typedef is not correct? 
Is there a way to define an adn_mat[N] array as typedef and later use it as multidimensional array?

thank you.

Comment: Should the `#define` and the  `typedef` be in `adj.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear from the question whether you want a 1-D array which you will index as if it is a 2-D, for example

```
adj_mat[3*row + col]
```

In this case, your declararations are only partially made. This compiles cleanly, I removed the `[N]` from your declaration and added an identifier to the function argument.

```
#define N 12
typedef int adj_mat[N];

void fill_mat_zero(adj_mat m) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        m[i] = 0;
}

int main(void){
    adj_mat mat;
    fill_mat_zero(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Or perhaps you want to make it 2-D by having an array of `adj_mat[]`.

```
#define N 12
typedef int adj_mat[N];

void fill_mat_zero(adj_mat *m, int size) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (j=0; j<size; j++)
            m[i][j] = 0;
}

int main(void){
    adj_mat mat[N];
    fill_mat_zero(mat, N);
    return 0;
}
```

But if you want to fill an array with `0` it is more efficient to use `memset()`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
#define N 12
typedef int adj_mat[N]
```

defines `adj_mat` as 12-element array of type `int`.

This

```
adj_mat mat[N];
```

defines `mat` as a 12-element array of type `adj_mat`, which means `mat` is actually an `int[12][12]`.  So you get the error.

And

```
void fill_mat_zero(adj_mat);
```

is a declaration, not a definition.  A definition has a body of code.  Think of a declaration as just like a customs declaration when you're entering a country - you **declare** that you have something, but the **declaration** isn't actually that thing.